# Azure IOT Central Complex Rules

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-central

I have to create some rules on Azure IOTCentral with some complexity. These device sensors have connectivity issues so some metrics need to be calculated in a time window using statistical methods to get the count of telemetry events that trigger an alert.

**Example:**

Agregation window 1 hour, rules will be like taking the mode of sensors values and counting if the reach 10. Other rules should launch the alert with a bigger aggregation window like 12hs

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Azure IoT Central doesn't support statistical functions in Rules so it would not be possible to create such a rule. You can suggest new product improvement ideas on [Azure IoT Central UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/911455-azure-iot-central).